# How do I get the absolute position of an element within a scrollable area in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

Let's say that I have a div `$container` with `position: relative`, and a div `$foo` within it with `position: absolute`. I want to get the position of `$foo` relative to the container. jQuery makes this easy:

```
$foo.position()
```

which returns an object with `top` and `left` properties, specified in pixels. The problem is, this number is no longer accurate if the container is scrolled down or to the right at all. Specifically, it changes, when it shouldn't. jQuery computes `position()` such that it's equivalent to `$foo.offset() - $container.offset()` (where `offset()` gives the window-relative position), and `$foo.offset()` changes as the user scrolls around `$container`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to take `$foo.position()` and then adjust is by adding `$container`'s `scrollTop()` and `scrollLeft()`.

This becomes annoying if you don't actually know what `$foo`'s relative container is. I've resorted to writing a function (in [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org)):

```
$.fn.container: ->
  $parent: @parent()
  if $parent.css('position') is 'relative'
    return $parent
  else
    return $parent.container()
```

Is there a more direct way that I'm overlooking? Or a direct way of finding an arbitrary element's container's scrollbar positions?

[**Update:** After reading Gaby's answer and comments, I cooked up a small jQuery plugin that goes through all of an element's parents and adds their `scrollTop()` and `scrollLeft()` to that element's `position()`. I haven't tested this thoroughly, so please try it and let me know if it works for you: [jqPositionWithScrolling plugin](http://gist.github.com/461529)

It's a little odd that `position()` doesn't do this automatically—I'd dare call it a bug.]

Comment: you would have to take into account `absolute` positioned containers as well.. and also stop when you reach the body tag..

Comment: Ah, I see. I'd forgotten that `position()` can be relative to an absolutely-positioned element as well as a relatively-positioned one. (Or a fixed-position one, for that matter. [Anything but `static`](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp).)

Answer (score 0):

Add the [`.scrollLeft()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) and [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) of the `$container` to the values returned by the `.position()` of the `$foo`

That should cover it ..

***Update***

To find the relative parent you should use the following

```
var $parent = $foo.parents()
                  .filter(
                       function(){
                            var position =  $(this).css('position')
                            return position==='relative' || position==='absolute';
                                 }
                         ).eq(0);
```

Comment: Yep, that's right. My question was poorly phrased... let's say you don't have a handle for `$container`. What then? In other words, how would you define a `$.fn.positionInRelativeContainer()` function?

Comment: I don't think that code will work, for 2 reasons: First, the `|| position==='absolute'` is a typo, right? Second, it will return every relative parent, not the closest one. I suppose that if there were potentially multiple nested scrolling elements, you'd want to add the `scrollLeft()` and `scrollTop()` from each. That sounds awfully computationally expensive, which is an issue if you want to redo the calculation in real-time as a user scrolls around.

Comment: Ah, just read your comment on my answer. Now I understand why `|| position==='absolute'` should be there. But shouldn't `position==='fixed'` also be there? Or the clause could just be `return position && position !== 'static'`.